# Changing cell color of excel sheet via VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am writing some data from database  to the excel via visual basic.net.I need to change background of some cells and also need to make text bold. I need something like that :

```
 xlWorkSheet.Cells(rownumber, 1).BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow
 xlWorkSheet.Cells(rownumber, 1).Font.isBold = True
```

Of course none of above is works.How can I achieve this? Thanks..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create a Excel.Style object, and apply that to a range. Like this:

```
Dim style As Excel.Style = xlWorkSheet.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add("NewStyle")
style.Font.Bold = True
style.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)

xlWorkSheet.Cells(rownumber, 1).Style = "NewStyle"
```

Comment: how can we do according to indexes like (1,1),(5,6) etc. not ranges like A1,B1.. ?

Comment: @dnur: xlWorkSheet.Cells(1,1) is of type Range, so *Controls.AddNamedRange(xlWorkSheet.Cells(rownumber, 1), "rangeStyles")* should work.

Comment: it gives an error at line which contains "Globals.ThisWorkbook". I changed itwith my workbook name "xlWorkBook" and "Globals.xlWorkBook" but none of them worked.
Also it gives second error at line which contains "Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.NamedRange" and I changed it with "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ShapeRange". is it true?

Comment: @dnur: I have updated the answer to make it better fit your situation (hopefully).

Answer (score 5):

This worked perfect for me.

xlsWorkSheet.Cells(row, column).interior.color = Color.Green

Answer (score 3):

Thats few declaration that can help you for style an Excel
For color palette: 
http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm

```
Dim xlsCell As Excel.Range
xlsCell = xlWorkSheet.Range("A1")
xlsCell.Range("A5").Value = "TEXT"

With xlsCell.Range("A12:J12")
    .Merge()
    .Borders(XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom).Weight = 2
    .Borders(XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop).Weight = 2
    .Borders(XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft).Weight = 2
    .Borders(XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight).Weight = 2
    .Borders(XlBordersIndex.xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = 2
    .Borders(XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical).Weight = 2
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 15                        
    .WrapText = True
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .VerticalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
    .HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    void SetCaptionStyle(ExcelStyle style)
    {
        style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(184, 204, 228));

    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain how to import and call this C# function from VB.NET?

Comment: I am new for this language. But I found some helping URL. Hope that will help you.
1) http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_page_format.htm
2) https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-excel-style-formatting/202

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
oWorkSheet.Range(oWorkSheet.Cells(nRow, 1), oWorkSheet.Cells(nRow, 5)).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.DimGray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dim style as:

```
Excel.Style = xlWorkSheet.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add("NewStyle")
style.Font.Bold = True
style.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)

xlWorkSheet.Cells(rownumber, 1).Style = "NewStyle"
```

Comment: please visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).